# average computation on Python

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib

I have this function which computes the average of y value for the same x, but it doesn't work when I have (x +/- eps).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from uncertainties import ufloat
from uncertainties.umath import * 

x = np.array([0, 0,1,1,2,2,2], float)
y = np.array([1, 2, 3,5,4, 4, 6.8], float)


def avg_group(x, y):
    A, ind, counts = np.unique(x, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
    B = y[ind]
    for dup in A[counts>1]:
        B[(A==dup)] = np.average(y[(x==dup)] )
        
    return A, B

new_x, new_y = avg_group(x, y)


plt.plot(new_x,new_y,'o')
plt.show()
```

How can I add a condition into avg_average to get the average of y (for an x+/- eps)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an in-built function for doing this. Even if there was, there is a little bit of ambiguity in the question. Consider a sequence like this:

```
x = x1, x1+eps, x1 + 2eps...
```

`x1` is close to `x1+eps` (ie within eps) but not close to `x1+2eps`. `x1+eps` is close to both `x1` and `x1+2eps`. Wo which x's do we treat as "same"? `x1` and `x1+eps` can be treated as same but so can `x1+eps` and `x2+eps`. For the sake of further discussion, I will that we will have two different x values in this case: `x1` and `x1+2eps`.

Assuming the above, we can iterate over sorted copy of x, and for each value of x, we check if it is close enough to previous value. If it is, we group it with the previous value else create a new entry.

I extended your code to implement the above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eps = 1e-5

x = np.array([0, 0,1,1,2,2,2], float)
y = np.array([1, 2, 3,5,4, 4, 6.8], float)


def avg_group(x, y):
  # sort by x-vales
  sorted_indices = np.argsort(x)
  x = x[sorted_indices]
  y = y[sorted_indices]

  sum_and_count = [(x[0], y[0], 1)]
  # we are maintaining a list of tupls of (x, sum of y, count of y)

  for index, (current_x, current_y) in enumerate(zip(x[1:], y[1:]), 1):
    # check if this x value is eps close to the previous x value
    previous_x = x[index-1]
    if current_x - previous_x <= eps:
      # This entry belongs to the previous tuple
      prev_tuple = sum_and_count[-1]
      new_tuple = (prev_tuple[0], prev_tuple[1]+current_y, prev_tuple[2]+1)
      sum_and_count[-1] = new_tuple
    else:
      # insert a new tuple
      new_tuple = (current_x, current_y, 1)
      sum_and_count.append(new_tuple)

  x, sum_y, count_y = zip(*sum_and_count)
  return np.asarray(x), np.asarray(sum_y) / np.asarray(count_y)


new_x, new_y = avg_group(x, y)


plt.plot(new_x,new_y,'o')
plt.show()
```

A colab notebook (with the code) is linked [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13quazgeC-1uF6Cdm7MWRz4fXIwvzxmG1?usp=sharing).

Let me know if this helps or if you have any followup questions :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

the code seems to work fine, but o want to change the new_x, i mean : '''if current_x - previous_x <= eps: ''' i want also to take the average of x

Comment: Replace `new_tuple = (prev_tuple[0], prev_tuple[1]+current_y, prev_tuple[2]+1)` by 
`new_tuple = ((prev_tuple[0] * prev_tuple[2] + current_x ) / (prev_tuple[2]+1)  , prev_tuple[1]+current_y, prev_tuple[2]+1)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `pandas.DataFrame`, instead of writing your own functions. By using  `pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy.mean()` on a new column of close-values you can get the expected result.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, 
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.r_[0.0, 0.05, 0.93, 1, 2.1, 1.95, 2  ], #added small values
                   'y':np.r_[1,   2,    3,    5, 4,   4,    6.8]})

dist = .3
df['close_ind'] = df['x'].sort_values().diff().gt(dist).cumsum()
x_new = df.groupby('close_ind')['x'].mean().tolist()
y_new = df.groupby('close_ind')['y'].mean().tolist()
```

> x_new: [0.025, 0.965, 2.017]
>
> y_new: [1.5, 4.0, 4.933]

Comment: Thank you, it's more efficient to use pandas, but i'm not sure that code works correctly with random x array.

Comment: The code above assumes, that the different groups of values `x[i]+-eps` (where eps is a small variation) are spaced larger from one another than `dist`. If not, you could try to histogram `x`.